# Error "No such file or directory" when i import a ".so" file and that file is available in python

Tags: python, importerror, raspberry-pi3, nao-robot

I have a python code and some nao files(naoqi.py,_inaoqi.so, ...) in a folder in a raspberry pi 3 model B v1.2 with armv7l. my code has some import line:

```
import sys
from naoqi import ALProxy
import time
import almath
import os
import socket
```

when i run this code i see "cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" error from second line :

```
from naoqi import ALProxy
```

and in below line in naoqi.py (in line `import _inaoqi`):

```
try:
    import _inaoqi
except ImportError:
    # quick hack to keep inaoqi.py happy
    if sys.platform.startswith("win"):
        print "Could not find _inaoqi, trying with _inaoqi_d"
        import _inaoqi_d as _inaoqi
    else:
        raise
```

this file is available, but i see "cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" error.

Why such an error occurs.

What can i do?

Comment: Please provide us with your code and tell us what have you tried so far.

Comment: @gonczor, i edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just dumping the inaoqi files into your program directory isn't sufficient, you have to package them properly as a "python module."  Is there an installer available for an inaoqi package, or can it be installed using pip?

Also, if you're running Python on Windows, the `.so` file isn't going to do you any good.  The C or C++ code for the module on Windows will be in a `.dll` file, so again, check to see if an installer for the module is available for your platform.